# Light detection by GPIO raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, voltage-divider, pnp, photoresistor

I have a cirtuit which consists of Resistor, Photoresistor, PNP Transistor, Voltage supply from raspberry pi like on the schema below:

[image]

Purpose of this circut is to detect light as a dawn detection sensor. As I know voltage on the base of transistor is expressed by voltage divider:

[image]

If the voltage on the base of transistor is 0.7V smaller than voltage on the emitter, then transistor conducts(change from darkness to light).

I would like to connect this circut to Raspbery pi GPIO port configured as INPUT with Pull up resistor and detect the light.

But I don't know how should I do it exaclty. Should I connection below collector directly to GPIO configured as input?

I would be grateful for some advices.

Maybe connection like below could work properly?

[image]

Best regards.

Comment: Um, that's not really a detector. That's a "the transistor gets warm or not, depending on how bright it is" circuit. What of this schematic do you want to attach to an input pin?

Comment: Agreed this circuit is not correct. The transistor is just shorting out the power supply when the photoresistor is in darkness.

Comment: Yes I would like to attach this circut to gpio input and detect light based on transistors activation.

Comment: Your update wont work. The GPIO is pulled to ground.

Comment: Why do you think you even need a transistor? Properly selected photocell and a resistor on it in many cases is sufficient. You can also use ADC input and trim the threshold in software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should want some hysteresis in the circuit. This can be achieved pretty simply:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyndPA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output will be **HI** to the I/O pin when there is no light and it will be **LO** when there is sufficient light. Feel free to adjust \$R_2\$ up or down a bit in order to select the desired light level for the circuit.

The above circuit provides an output that reaches the rail voltage but does not reach ground (it should get within a diode drop, though.) If you want to have a rail-to-rail output then you'll need to add another active device to buffer the output.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you pull the gpio pin up to 3.3v using a sizeable resistor ,and then pulling down that same pin by connecting it to the collector

here is a Quick solution , please calculate the values depending on the components you are using.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc3gHA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

hope it helps.

Comment: oh you are right, my bad,ill fix that.

Comment: Is pull up resistor is the same which internally resistor in Raspberry connected to GPIO port? I can activate it in Python.

Comment: I suppose so, if it is the same as in the Arduino types where you declare a PULL_UP  in the pin initialisation. So then you can connect the collector directly to the gpio pin and just erase that resistor from circuit